# Why should I run OWASP Broken Web Applications Project as host only or NAT?

Tags: network, owasp

We have a hard time getting VMWare to work in bridged mode. We can get it to work in Bridged mode.
Why is it so important to run it with host only or NAT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name 'Broken Web Applications' infer that they are a collection of applications which has insecure code deliberately put together for educational or practice purposes.

Using Bridged mode means, other users in your network can connect to this host. 
So technically if you are running 'OWASP BWA' using bridged mode, others in your network or LAN can exploit this insecure code and get access to your machine or the machine hosting this 'BWA'. We wouldn't want that and so using NAT ( if you need this host only for outgoing connections such as to the Internet, not allowing incoming connections ). Host only network gives access only to other VM's running under the same hypervisor, with no external access.
Therefore NAT, Host-Only networking provide limited access to this VM running insecure code.
It is strongly suggested NOT* to run 'OWASP BWA' or any other such intended insecure application in Bridge-mode.

Comment: So it is for protecting the Virtual Machine from other computers, rather than the other way around?